# How do I specify a column that uses [with] method in laravel querybuilder?

Tags: laravel, relational-database

Examples table
↓column

```
user_id | monster_id | created_at | updated_at
```

I want to switch the relation method by column value of Example table when getting other table data through example table.

For example, Example Model has below relation method.

```
public function one() 
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Model\TableModel\One');
}

public function two() 
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Model\TableModel\Two');
}
```

This time,
If Example table user_id is one and monster id is 2 or 3 or 4. I want to use one() method.
And if user_id is 7 or 8 or 9 and monster _id is 1. I want to use two() method.

When that how querybuilder do i write.

I tried below code but [with] method has no return.

But i guess this reason is [with] method is in [Where].

```
    $user = Example::Where(function ($query) {
       $query->where('user_id', 1)
             ->whereIn('monster_id', [ 2, 3, 4 ] )
             ->with(['one' => function ($query) {
                 $query->where(~~)->get();
               }]);
     })->orWhere(function ($query) {
       $query->where('monster_id', 1)
             ->whereIn('user_id', [ 7, 8, 9 ] )
             ->with(['one' => function ($query) {
                 $query->where(~~)->get();
               }]);
     })->get();
```

Please give me advice.

Comment: give more details show the relations for which you are using with, complete the question you want to ask

Answer (score 0):

You can define a static function in your `User` model, I guess you are using with() for relationships, but I would say you should add this in your model,

```
public static function getVariedPosts($where=array(), $orwhere=array())
{

    return self::where(function ($query) {
            $query->with(["post" => function($q){
                $q->where($where);
            }])
      })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->with(["post2" => function($q){
                $q->where($orwhere);
            }])
      })->paginate(10)
}
```

you can use it in controller

```
$where = ['status', 2];
$orwhere = ['status', 3];
$userposts = User::getVariedPosts($where, $orwhere);
```

Comment: Thank you ! But this solution is not what i ask. I want to choice either [with] method I use . by current table column value.  So I guess [with] method has no need to use closure.

Comment: your question has so much less written earlier, there are no gods sitting in stackoverflow, I wrote what I understood, so please think about how easy you can make for the person who is spending time & resources for your help, your question feels like I want something grant me this wish stackoverflow, explain your situation so that the person answering does not misunderstand